# FACEBOOK Login with Custom Button

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have implemented custom button for Facebook Login, Everything is happening but I am not getting call backs `onSuccess` or `onCancel` or `onError` so that I can get the returned results.

I am using  face book `SDK` version `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0`

**Below is the code for reference**

```
public class OnBoardingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = OnBoardingActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
    private CallbackManager mCallBackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

 final RelativeLayout facebookSignUp = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.facebook_signupButton);
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallBackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, " Login successfull +++  ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, " Login got canceled ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, " Error in the login with exception is =  " + e);
            }
        });

           facebookSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(OnBoardingActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
            }
        });

}
```

Below is the snippet of Facebook Login

```
<application>
  <!-- To use Facebook Login or Share below activity is declared -->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    </application>
```

Added XML Layout snipet

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/facebook_signupButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#3a569d">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/login_with_facebook"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_facbook_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_with_facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Login with facebook"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting callback in `onError` then? If so, share the exception logs here.

Comment: No I am not getting any callback , I am surprised why I am not getting any call back

Comment: show us your mainfest please

Comment: Instead of  this - `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(OnBoardingActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));` you can directly set the permissions to login button. try that once.

Comment: I am not using their login button , I am using my button , is it not possible to login with facebook without their login button ?

Comment: @mina , I have added manifest

Comment: @Nagendra It is possible without using their login button. But I suggest you try using their login button once.

Comment: if you not using there button , please provide your xml code where the login button

Comment: It is difficult to customise their login button for example placing small F icon on button either left or right . thats why I am using pure custom button,

Comment: @mina I have added XML snippet please have a look

Comment: so your textview its login button

Comment: No it is whole relative layout , I have edited the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to make you code look more smart 
you have first Initialize Facebook SDK before set your layout

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

when use click on button or in your case layout call method do whole function

```
facebookSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fblogin();
            }
        });
```

here private method handle Facebook login and callback

```
private void Fblogin()
{
    callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    // Set permissions 
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email","user_photos","public_profile"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    System.out.println("Success");
                    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                                        // handle error
                                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Success");
                                        try {

                                            String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                            System.out.println("JSON Result"+jsonresult);

                                            String str_email = json.getString("email");
                                            String str_id = json.getString("id");
                                            String str_firstname = json.getString("first_name");
                                            String str_lastname = json.getString("last_name");

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }).executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG_CANCEL,"On cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) { 
                    Log.d(TAG_ERROR,error.toString());
                }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I provide you whole code to parse your json file

Comment: I have just added onActivityResult and its working like charm, Thanks a lot for saving my time

Comment: I guess its is a valid question , so this question should be accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Kotlin version

**1.** Create `callbackManager` as an object of your activity:

`lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager`

**2**. Set `setOnClickListener` for the Facebook button:

`facebookButton.setOnClickListener { loginWithFacebook() }`

**3.** Implement the `loginWithFacebook` as below:

```
private fun loginWithFacebook() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, setOf("email"))
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                result?.let {
                    Log.d("facebook", it.accessToken.token)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(this@YourActivity, "Facebook login cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@YourActivity, "Facebook login failed: ${error.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
    }
```

**4.** Override `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```